# Custom action as 64 bit process

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a setup destined for 64 bit platforms. In that setup I referenced a C# custom action project that is build 64 bit. In one of functions, I noticed that process is 32 bit and not 64. Why is that and how can I make it 64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host for your managed custom action (`SfxCA.dll`) is picked based on the `$(Platform)` of your custom action project. You can see the appropriate .dll being picked in the `wix.ca.targets`. The bitness of the `SfxCA.dll` will control the bitness of the custom action server. The Windows Installer will automatically pick the right custom action server.

So, it all comes down to whether your `$(Platform)` was set to `x64` to get a 64-bit custom action server.

Note: 64-bit packages can carry and execute 32-bit custom actions but not the other way around, of course.