# WiX Custom Actions in 64 bit

Tags: wix, 64-bit, windows-installer, custom-action

I am trying to run a managed custom action in WiX 3.5 as a 64 bit process.  All projects involved are configured to be built in x64 (as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495998/custom-action-as-64-bit-process)).
My understanding is that the key to this is the sfxca version.  According to my build log, it is calling the x64 version properly.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\..\sdk\MakeSfxCA.exe" "C:\Projects\WiXInstaller\MyCustomActions\obj\x64\Debug\MyCustomActions.CA.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\..\sdk\x64\SfxCA.dll" "C:\Projects\WiXInstaller\MyCustomActions\obj\x64\Debug\MyCustomActions.dll" "C:\lib\wix35\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll;..\builds\source\OtherDll.dll;C:\Projects\WiXInstaller\MyCustomActions\CustomAction.config"
```

But when I run the installer, the log still says "Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server," and the custom action doesn't run correctly.

Specifically I am trying to run the 64 bit version of Powershell instead of the 32 bit version.

Comment: DTF ca's are set to Any CPU by default.  The native hook is 32bit but the CA process is 64bit.

Comment: I changed it from Any CPU to x64 specifically to force the correct sfxca version.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would matter.  The sfxca is just used to start everything up and marshal the interop calls.  I've run 64bit code without having to do this in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on either.  My research has given me the impression that I should have the 64 bit impersonated server available to me, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: But why would you need it? The native hook merely has access to the MSI handle and marshals the calls.  It's the managed portion that needs to be able to run in 64bit.

Comment: I think that the hook still determines whether or not the managed portion is run in 64bit.
I did figure out the problem, though, and it is stupid of me.  Because I forgot to change a path, the custom actions were being compiled totally correctly but then the wix project was grabbing the old custom actions instead.  
Changing the hook to x64 did get the x64 version of PowerShell to run for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you explicitly compile your managed code to be 64-bit then DTF will correctly load your custom action into the 64-bit custom action server. By default managed code compiles to "Any CPU" which will cause your custom action to be loaded in the 32-bit custom action server.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I accepted this as the answer even though really the problem was my own stupidity - this will be the problem for most people stumbling on this question.  Thank you!

Comment: I compiled the WiX installer project in 64 bit, and it still runs the 32 bit Action Server. How did you get it to load the 64 bit??

Comment: I would like to ask the same question @codenamezero asked

Comment: For anyone who is wondering. You can fix this by setting the installer and custom action to x64 bit in the Configuration Manager. My collegue BigIskender had the same issue, credits to him